# Сбор данных и отправка их на другую страницу(редирект)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть у меня на сайте форма, с которой нужно собрать данные. Дело в том, что:
1) эти данные находятся не только в `<input>`, но и в разных `<div>`, `<span>` и атрибутах. Так что, мне эти данные нужно собирать при помощи jQuery. **Вопрос:** как мне на стороне php парсить эти данные?
2) на стороне PHP мне эти данные нужно валидировать(что я знаю, как сделать) и если всё в порядке, то нужно перенаправить пользователя на другую страницу, с которой при помощи ajax-запросить эти самые данные. **Вопрос:** это делается при помощи сессий и как это вообще можно реализовать?

Comment: Собирайте в объект, сериализуйте в JSON и отправляйте в PHP - скрипт. Скрипт должен ответить результатами валидации. Как передат данные между скриптами - ваше дело. Можно и сессиями.

Comment: 1) Отправить форму или ajax на вашу php страницу с обработкой. 2) По окончанию валидации php страница может сразу перенаправить пользователя на другую страницу и сунуть туда данные, добытые с 1ой страницы (ведь это все одно действие - прием + валидация+перенаправление+проброс данных). Нет? Или я что-то путаю

Comment: @alexoander да, это всё именно так, но мне бы примеры, как получать данные на стороне PHP, если они не из формы(ведь если получать данные из формы, то будет `$_POST['input_name']`, а если это просто `var`-переменная в js-коде, то как тогда?). Ну и пример, как запомнить данные, отправленные в php-файл, чтобы после ридеректа их можно было забрать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим у Вас есть блок с данными:

```
<div>
   <span id="data1">1</span>
   <div id="data2">2</div>
   <textarea id="comment">comment</textarea>
</div>
```

Вы собираете данные либо $('form').serializeArray() это если форма, если как в данном примере, то можете просто по id или по классу.

```
var data = {
   data1: $('#data1').text().trim(),
   data2: $('#data2').text().trim(),
   comment: $('#comment').text().trim(),
}
```

Потому эти данные отправляете на сервер. Функция Jquery называется [аякс](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Отправляем данные

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: "post",
    data: {
          data:data
          },

    success: function (response) {
        alert('Всё прошло гладко');
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('Ошибка');
    }
});
```

В файле test.php уже можно работать с данными

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете например создавать налету новые input при отправке формы по клику на кнопку с `id = pay-invoices`. Пример с ajax запросом

```
$(document).on('submit', '#pay-invoices', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var input = $('input[name=invoices]').val(JSON.stringify(selectedInvoices));

    var $form = $(this);
    $form.append($(input));

    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data: new FormData($form[0]),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {
            // do something
        },
        error: function (response) {
            // do something
        }
    });
});
```